# How to keep image file extension when exporting LyX to LaTeX

Tags: graphics, lyx, export, epub

With the workflow:

LyX -> LaTeX -> ePub (via pandoc)

And I'm having a problem where an image filename included in LyX (say "image.jpg") will be converted into "image" (no extension) in LaTeX. pandoc will then obviously complain it can't find the images.

Is there any way (short of parsing the LaTeX and adding the file extensions externally) of configuring LyX to keep them? (I'm using LyX's own export to LaTeX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think you can configure the export from Lyx this way, because LaTeX usually adds the extensions.

But what is the point against using regular expressions and changing "includegraphics{([a-z]...)}" against "includegraphics{\1.jpg}", details depend on the editor?

Learning regular expressions at least a bit is always worth the time.

Comment: Nothing against regex except Lundh's lemma: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems."