# Image path when exporting from Lyx

Tags: lyx, markdown, export, restructured-text

I am trying to setup LyX to export directly to the reStructuredText format. I adapted [these instructions](https://lemmster.de/lyx-export-to-markdown.html) just replacing markdown with reStructuredText.

Unfortunately LyX changes the path of every image. [Here](https://latex.org/forum/download/file.php?id=11056) is a short example.

e.g. this figure

```
.. figure:: 0_home_muzzle_Nextcloud_Stuff_Stuff_documentation_source_img_pressure.jpg
   :alt: Pressure
   :width: 80.0%

   Pressure
```

should be

```
.. figure:: img/pressure.jpg
   :alt: Pressure
   :width: 80.0%

   Pressure
```

LyX replaces the image path with that of the copy of the image created to allow the converter to do its job. This is the correct behavior if the output format will somehow embed the image in the document, but that is not the case for reStructuredText (or for markdown, for that matter).

If I export the lyx file as latex from the GUI, and then convert it to reStructuredText using the command

```
pandoc --wrap=none -f latex -t rst -o file.rst file.tex
```

the image path is correct, is there a way to obtain the same effect from the UI conversion and export system?

Btw, someone had a [similar issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192090/how-to-keep-image-file-extension-when-exporting-lyx-to-latex) 5 years ago, but it does not look like it was ever properly solved.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=33197&p=111754#p111754 and also on the LyX mailing list. Please always reference your cross-posts.

Comment: Look like that you are converting  the temporal version (that showed with Ctrl+R preview) instead of the final version (that produced with FIle > Export )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @fran for the hint, exporting the final version of the file (by adding the `nice` flag to the export command) helped. Unfortunately this causes lyx to remove the image extension from the filename.

The best workaround I have found to this is to manually specify the image extension in the conversion command:

```
pandoc --wrap=none -s --default-image-extension=jpg  -f latex -t rst -o $$o $$i
```

Unfortunately this means that you have to convert all your images int one format. This is not an ideal solution and I hope someone comes up with a better one.

In any case if you want to automate the process you can create a new converter in the LyX GUI.

Navigate to `Tools > Preferences > File Handling > File Formats` and add the rst format.

[image: Add the rst format]

The go to `Tools > Preferences > File Handling > Converters` and create the converter using the command above and the Extra flag `nice`.

[image: Atthe the latex to rst converter]

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to make sure the image-file names converted from .tex file to the .rst file have the right extension is adding the proper option to pandoc, like:

--default-image-extension=png

Of course, all image files must than have this extension, which may be a caveat, but doable, when aware of the problem.

The pandoc documentation says:

--default-image-extension=EXTENSION

"Specify a default extension to use when image paths/URLs have no extension. This allows you to use the same source for formats that require different kinds of images. Currently this option only affects the Markdown and LaTeX readers."

Answer (score -1):

might not be solving you'r exact problem, but I came across an identical problem trying to compile lyx to html with pandoc. after quite a lot of digging, I concluded that in general lyx and pandoc don't mesh together, and you have to fix up the latex file that is exported from lyx before giving it to pandoc. so, I made this python script that does exactly that. for me (with html) this works perfectly!  (after several days of pulling hairs). I even managed to add some key bindings so a single keystroke compiles to html and opens up a preview in my browser. I tried to document the process well enough, mostly for me to be able to reproduce in the futer, but also if someone finds this usefull than that would be great.

for more information, [here is the git page of the repository](https://lioravrahami.github.io/automate_compile_lyx_with_pandoc/):